# Missing gnu/stubs-64.h in 32bit ubuntu on 64bit machine while compiling hyperterm

Tags: compiling

I've try to compile [hyperterm](https://github.com/zeit/hyperterm) but I have error that `sys/cdefs.h` is missing I have it in `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h` so I call:

```
CPATH=/usr/include:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu scripts/install.sh
```

but then I got error that gnu/stubs-64.h is missing from

```
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h:10:27
```

I'm on 32bit system (`uname -i` return `i686`) but the machine is 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this I've installed: g++-multilib and libc6-dev-amd64